# How to destroy all child widgets with a certain type

Tags: qt

I've created some QPushButtons using a loop over a `QFrame` and some other widgets

```
// Creation of some other widgets here ...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton( this );
    b->show();
}
```

Now I'd like to destroy all the QPushButtons without touching the other widgets, How can I target them ?

*nb: I'm not using layouts*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all buttons in the following way:

```
QList<QPushButton *> allPButtons = parentWidget.findChildren<QPushButton *>();
```

Than you can delete them all

```
qDeleteAll(allButtons);
allButtons.clear();
```

Comment: You can reduce this to a one-liner: `qDeleteAll(parentWidget.findChildren<QPushButton *>());`

Answer (score 2):

Keep a collection of all the QPushButtons and iterate through the collection to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

```
QList<QPushButton *> Buttons;    


for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton( this );
    Buttons << b;
    b->show();

}
```

So now you can delete only the buttons you created on that loop.

```
qDeleteAll(allButtons);
allButtons.clear();
```